# Bitwise Property Values in Designer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have an abstract user control(baseModule) that has a property that I plan on using a bitwise comparison on to determine what export types are supported by that module.  In the designer of a module derived from baseModule, I am presented with a combobox with the ability to just select a single value (Html, Xml, etc.)  I would like to be presented with a drop-down checked listbox so I could select which values I want.

How can I accomplish this inside of VS2008?  I've seen other properties support this.  Please refer to the code below for a better explanation of what I mean in the poorly asked question above.

```
Public Class ExportTypes
    Public Enum ExportType
        Html = 1
        Xml = 2
        Xls = 4
        Txt = 8
        Pdf = 16
        Rtf = 32
    End Enum
End Class

Public Class baseModule
    Private _SupportedExportTypes As ExportType = 0
    Public Property SupportedExportTypes() As ExportType
        Get
            Return _SupportedExportTypes
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As ExportType)
            _SupportedExportTypes = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to implement a [`UITypeEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx). Check [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx), and exchange the created control in the custom type editor (in the `EditValue` method override) to a [`CheckedListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx), and handle assigning and retrieving the enum values to and from the listbox. Then decorate the property in your user control with an [`EditorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) point out your type editor, and you should be good to go.

Comment: THe links above pointed me in the right direction.  Luckily I found a c# project that had done all the work for me and introduced the FlagsAttribute to me for Enums.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/flagenumeditor.aspx?msg=1453046